# How to catch CTRL+C in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, signals

I have a simple single threaded Clojure program that creates a temp file for swapping data.  When the program exits normally this file is deleted, however when the program is exited via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> that bit of code never executes.  I need it to execute regardles sof how the program exits. I know that I need to catch that signal (I've done this before in other languages), but I can't seem to figure out how to do it in Clojure.

Comment: It would be very interesting to find out if there's a native Clojure solution. I'm assuming this problem has to do with console applications, not GUI, like Seesaw.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I don't know if Clojure has wrapped method for that purpose. In java, you can use [Runtime.addShutdownHook()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread))

> Registers a new virtual-machine shutdown hook.
>
> The Java virtual machine shuts down in response to two kinds of events:
>
> - The program exits normally, when the last non-daemon thread exits or when the exit (equivalently, System.exit) method is invoked, or
> - The virtual machine is terminated in response to a user interrupt, such as typing ^C, or a system-wide event, such as user logoff or system shutdown.

#### Update

Here is a simple demo

```
(.addShutdownHook (Runtime/getRuntime) (Thread. (fn [] (println "Shutting down..."))))

user=> ;; Ctrl-C
Shutting down...
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [deleteOnExit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#deleteOnExit%28%29) method in the java.io.File:

```
(import '(java.io File))
(doto (File/createTempFile "foo" nil nil) (.deleteOnExit))
```