# Gracefully exit a Clojure core.async go loop on kill

Tags: java, clojure, signals, core.async

I have a top-level [core.async](https://github.com/clojure/core.async/) go loop. I want it to run indefinitely, at least until I signal it to stop with CTRL-C or [kill](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/kill.1.html) or similar. I'm currently using [java.lang.Runtime/addShutdownHook](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29) like this:

```lisp
(ns async-demo.core
  (:require [clojure.core.async :as async
             :refer [<! >! <!! timeout chan alt! go]]))
(defn run [] (go (loop [] (recur))))
(.addShutdownHook (Runtime/getRuntime) (Thread. #(println "SHUTDOWN")))
```

Here are my problems:

1. If I start the REPL and `(run)` then it starts and runs in a background thread. When I exit the REPL, I don't see the desired shutdown message.
2. However, when I run from `lein run`, the go loop exits immediately and displays "SHUTDOWN".

Neither is what I want.

I don't necessarily expect to find a solution that works for all JVM's. I develop on a Mac and deploy to Ubuntu, so I'd like to find a solution that works for both:

- Mac JVM: java version "1.7.0_45" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
- Ubuntu JVM: java version "1.7.0_25" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.3.10) (7u25-2.3.10-1ubuntu0.12.04.2) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709639/how-to-catch-ctrlc-in-clojure

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18612063/clojure-core-async-cpu-hangs-after-timeout

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`go` function returns a channel. You may want to `(close! chan)` in shutdown hook.

If you run `lein run` you need a main function that will call `(run)` to start go thread.

```
(ns async-demo.core
  (:require [clojure.core.async :as async
             :refer [<! >! <!! timeout chan alt! go close!]]))

(def ch (atom nil))

(defn run []
  (go (while true
        (<! (timeout 500))
        (prn "inside go"))))

(defn -main [& args]
  (println "Starting")
  (reset! ch (run))
  (.addShutdownHook (Runtime/getRuntime)
                    (Thread. #(do
                                (println "SHUTDOWN")
                                (close! @ch))))
  (while true
    (<!! @ch)))
```

Comment: Are you seeing the shutdown message when you (a) run from the REPL; (b) run via `lein run`?

Comment: There is no shutdown message in case (a) `lein repl`, case (b) `lein run` does display shutdown

Comment: If I run `lein trampoline repl` shutdown display when I exit with `Ctrl-D` or using `(exit)` function

Comment: I don't understand why it's an accepted answer. It's wrong because closing a channel returned by `go` from outside doesn't stop while-loop

Answer (score 13):

You can use a signalling `exit-ch` and do a conditional to see if you should exit the loop. The channel + conditional is better handled in clojure by [alt!](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core.async/alt!):

```
(ns async-demo.core
  (:require [clojure.core.async :refer [chan go-loop alt! timeout put!]]))

(defn run
  []
  (let [exit-ch (chan)]
    (go-loop []
      (alt!
         (timeout 10) (recur)
         exit-ch nil
    exit-ch

(let [exit-ch (run)]
  (.addShutdownHook (Runtime/getRuntime) (put! exit-ch true)))
```

If you just `close!` the channel, it won't stop the loop from running. Also, [don't need to start a go block just to send a value to a channel](https://clojure.org/guides/core_async_go#_general_advice).

Answer (score -1):

Regarding part 1: "When I exit the REPL, I don't see the desired shutdown message." I think the shutdown thread isn't connected to `lein repl`'s console.

Regarding part 2: After the go loop is started, it runs in background threads. Since the main thread exits after creating the go block, the program shuts down. To make the loop long-lived it needs to be put in a normal `loop`. (It is also way nicer to put a `Thread/sleep` inside!)